# 3 checkboxes with same name and same same numeric value

Tags: php, checkbox

Given this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Coke" name="Price" value="70" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Fanta" name="Price" value="70" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Sprite" name="Price" value="70" />
```

I would like to know how, if my user selects Fanta checkbox, I want my php variable `$type="Fanta"` but I need form checkbox VALUES to stay NUMERIC for total price calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you're asking, but I believe you basically want 2 fields, one that defines the price and one that defines the selected type.

In that case, your best bet would be to store the prices server-side (That way people can't modify them too, which is good!). If you do this, your checkboxes will look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Coke" name="type[]" value="Coke" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Fanta" name="type[]" value="Fanta" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Sprite" name="type[]" value="Sprite" />
```

Your backend code would look like this:

```
 $prices = array(
     'Coke' => 70,
     'Fanta' => 70,
     'Sprite' => 70
 );

 $types = $_POST['type'];
 $total = 0;

 foreach($types as $key => $type) {
     if (!isset($prices[$type]))
         continue;

     $total += $prices[$type];
 }

 // Use $total as your total price for whatever calculation
 echo $total;
```

---

As per your comment, if you still want these prices client side for calculations, you can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to output it into a script tag and use the prices directly. It's basically going to turn the server-side prices array into a client-side array of prices.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prices = <?= json_encode($prices) ?>;

    // Now you can use prices['Coke'] etc, based off the value of the selected checkbox.
</script>
```

Comment: But what the case if he has checkboxes morethan that..??

Comment: @GautamD3164 Then he adds more prices?!

Comment: Thank you for that amazing response, I will give this a try and see how it goes. The only reason why I wanted the values to be a number is because when the user selects a checkbox the total price will display at the bottom of form using a java script.

Comment: @user2087655 I see! Well, let me update my answer to show you what you can do for that ;)

Comment: Not like that....if he add 20 checkboxes as per your code he need to create array $prices for 20 right..??

Comment: @GautamD3164 Yes, of course. Just like he would have to anyway, otherwise where would the price come from?!

Comment: exlent @RudiVisser...for tough question...tough answer.may i call this tit for tat..anyway +1 for you

Comment: Thanks a million for all your help Rudi, I renamed form to match above example and I get a value "0" in mysql database when using $total to insert the price of items. How do I get the price of what checkbox is checked.

Comment: @user2087655 My apologies; I'd made a slight mistake in the HTML. The `name` of the checkbox elements needs to be `name="type[]"`, not just `name="type"`. If you change that, it should start working just fine :)

Comment: Thanks Rudi, I have done so and tested. but when I use $total to get price of selected checkbox I get value 0 in mysql DB

Comment: echo $total; echo $prices; dispalys 0Array

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://rudiv.se/stack/user2087655.php), where I've tested the code is working as expected. I've provided full code at the bottom too.

Comment: Hi Rudi, could you please advise if you have time on how I get values into mysql seperate columns if a user selects two checkboxes belonging to same array. e.g user selects coke and fanta then the data goes to column softtype1 = coke and column softtype2 = fanta

Comment: You have an array of the types which you can just insert into different columns if you want to. Just use `foreach($types as $type)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Rudi, you are the best. You have helped me complete the form side of things. :)

Comment: @user2087655 Not a problem - Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how, if my user selects Fanta checkbox,

Then name you field `fanta`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Fanta" name="fanta" value="70" />
```

Once you have done that you can get the values using either the [`$_POST` or the `$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) (depending on your form method):

```
if (isset($_POST['fanta'])) {
    echo $_POST['fanta'];
}
```

**However you should never ever ever rely on the prices coming from the clientside!**

> but I need form checkbox VALUES to stay NUMERIC for total price calculation.

That is not going to happen because in HTTP values are being send as strings. Luckily PHP does automatic [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) for you so you will still be able to do calculations with the string values.

http://codepad.viper-7.com/GOhHdz

In some situations you want to make it a integer value explicitly. In that case you can use [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting):

```
var_dump((int) '18');
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/kJlGoS

Answer (score 0):

When you post a form, anyway you will get 70 as value.

```
echo $_POST['Price'];
```

gives 70

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Coke" name="Price" rel=70 />
<input type="checkbox" value="Fanta" name="Price" rel="70" />
<input type="checkbox" value="Sprite" name="Price" rel="70" />
```

use javascript to get rel attribute value for selected checkbox for total price